# Help extending a function

Tags: delphi, function

I found a function which will extract a word that is between 2 other words and this works well but I would like to extend the function so it scan the entire string that I choose and extract ALL of the words that are between the 2 keywords and not just the first one it comes to. I am guessing I will need to add a loop of some kind but I am new to Delphi so I do not know exactly what I need to do and I could use some help.

Anyway here is the function that I was talking about.

```
function GetAWord(sentence, word1, word2 : string) : string;
  var
    n : integer;
  begin
  n := pos(word1, sentence);
  if n = 0 then begin
    result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  delete(sentence, 1, n + length(word1) - 1);
  n := pos(word2, sentence);
  if n = 0 then begin
    result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  result := copy(sentence, 1, n - 1);
  end;
```

Thank You,
Emily

Comment: The function extracts a whole substring (not just a single word) between word1 and word2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I know it can return more than just one word but I am using in a way that will only return just a single word. What I need to do is to extend it so it will not just stop at the first word it comes to. Here is an example: I have 3 cats named <word1>momo<word2> <word1>charlie<word2> & <word1>kiwi<word2>. I need to get all 3 words out of that string. IE. momo,charlie,kiwi. Hope that makes more sense now and thank you again for your reply.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, Emily. Your original description was that instead of returning `momo`, your function should return `momo <word2> <word1>charlie<word2> <word1>kiwi`. That is, as you said, "ALL of the words." But your comment suggests you want to return a *list* of words (instead of just one string), and that the delimiter words should *not* be included in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an additional argument to the function:

```
function GetAWord(sentence, word1, word2 : string; Index: Integer) : string;
var
  N: integer;

begin
  repeat
    N:= pos(word1, sentence);
    if N = 0 then begin
      result := '';
      exit;
    end;
    delete(sentence, 1, n + length(word1) - 1);
    n := pos(word2, sentence);
    if n = 0 then begin
      result := '';
      exit;
    end;
    Dec(Index);
    if Index < 0 then begin
      result := copy(sentence, 1, n - 1);
      Exit
    end;
    delete(sentence, 1, n + length(word2) - 1);
  until False;
end;


// test
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = '115552211666221177722';

begin
  ShowMessage(GetAWord(S, '11', '22', 0));
  ShowMessage(GetAWord(S, '11', '22', 1));
  ShowMessage(GetAWord(S, '11', '22', 2));
  ShowMessage(GetAWord(S, '11', '22', 4));
end;
```

---

Well you can find all entries in a single function:

```
procedure ParseSentence(sentence, word1, word2 : string; Strings: TStrings);
var
  N: integer;

begin
  Strings.Clear;
  repeat
    N:= pos(word1, sentence);
    if N = 0 then exit;
    delete(sentence, 1, n + length(word1) - 1);
    n := pos(word2, sentence);
    if n = 0 then exit;
    Strings.Add(copy(sentence, 1, n - 1));
    delete(sentence, 1, n + length(word2) - 1);
  until False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = '115552211666221177722';

var
  SL: TStringList;

begin
  SL:= TStringList.Create;
  ParseSentence(S, '11', '22', SL);
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(SL);
  SL.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help but I am not sure how this might help if I did not know how many words were in the original string that needed to be indexed. I am pretty new to programming (obviously) so that's why I ask if this would work with any string even if I do not know how many indexes of the keywords there are in the string ?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick (both actully work) but the 2nd one is better for my needs. Thanks again